# magento populate fields in order creation for customer

Tags: magento

I have an external application with the contacts on a database server db1 ,second i have magento database db2 in the same server.
I want to populate the customer dropdown in the adminpanel with contacts information 
how can i do it ?

Comment: Which customer dropdown is this?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this to connect another DB:
`
$config = array(
    'host'      => $data['db_host'],
    'username'  => $data['db_user'],
    'password'  => $data['db_pass'],
    'dbname'    => $data['db_name']
);

$connection = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->createConnection('connection_name', 'pdo_mysql', $config);
`

Then on `$connection` You can use `fetchAll()` etc.

And from now You can prepare "dropdown" items if that's what You want.